# existence of solution of ODE with one sided Lipschitz right hand side

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I know that in any ODE, the right hand side should be continuous or Lipschitz to guarantee the existence of a solution, in my research, I came across an ODE where the right hand side is one sided Lipschitz but I cannot find any resource about the way to prove that existence, can any one please guide me to a book or articles which could give me these information? The ODE is: 
\begin{align*}
\begin{cases}
&\dfrac{d y(t)}{d t} = f(y(t))\\
&y(0) = x_{0}
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
for almost every where $t\geq 0$ and $y(t)$ is absolutely continuous.
Thanks very much for any one could help.

Comment: Hi, I am just wondering why I do not get any answer ( hint or guidance for a resource or any little comment!) for any of my questions? Are they really difficult? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You will most likely not find one.
As far as I see it, the one-sided Lipschitz conditions ensures uniqueness of the solution (here is a nice reference for the uniqueness:

chapter "IV.12 B-Stability and Contractivity" (p180) of book
"Solving  Ordinary Differential Equations II" by E. Hairer  G. Wanner 
http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-3-642-05221-7 )

For the existence part, the results that exist are much more general. In fact, to get existence one only needs integrability of $f$, but you can get away with say Locally Lipschitz assumption on $f$. For the one-sided case, I usually see assumptions of the type: $\exists L>0$ $\exists q\in\mathbb{N}$  $\forall y,y'\in \mathbb{R}$  $|f(y)-f(y')|\leq K (1+|y|^q+|y'|^q)|y-y'|$.

I still trying to get the arguments fully sorted, but using locally Lip one establishes a solution in a small interval, then the one-sided Lipschitz allows you to control the growth of the solution and hence you can extend the solution to an arbitrary large interval.